# Paypal verify donation and check transaction id

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn

I've used this tutorial [Donation Center PHP-MySQL Paypal API](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/)

In the guide they use $_POST['txn_id'] to verify the transaction ID at the return page but for some reason I don't receive any $_POST['txn_id'] value.

The IPN.php page should add the transaction ID to another table as well but it does not seam to work for me either. The IPN simulator does however work and the "handshake is confirmed".
How would I verify a donation and put the transaction ID into a table, the esiest and safest way?

Comment: are you testing the payment live or sandbox?

Comment: I tested it via sandbox and got the "handshake" confirmed for the IPN and I've tested it live as well and it seams to be working fine except that I don't get any $_POST values back

Comment: in sandbox, you will not get payment status `completed` as you are trying in code `if($p->ipn_data['payment_status']=='Completed')`, the paypal send payment status as `Pending` so if you change this `if($p->ipn_data['payment_status']=='Pending')` you will see the trans id saved in database. when you will be done and go live change it back to `Completed`

Comment: I'm currently using if($p->ipn_data['payment_status']=='Completed') in IPN.php while live testing it and it does not seam to work for me

Comment: are you facing problem only with $_POST['txn_id'] value or nothing inserting in database at all?

Comment: I got my IPN to successfully insert the data into my SQL table. The return page however does not get any $_POST['txn_id'] value. Is there something I have to include in that page as well? Like the Paypal Integration Class I use for the IPN page ?

Comment: no, as far my knowledge, paypal doesn't send any information on `return_url`

Comment: if you saved information into database before sending the customer to paypal, then get the row id, encrypt it, pass it with `return_url` e.g `thankyou.php?id=encrypedid` and then on `return_url` just fetch the encrypted id from link, decrypt it and fetch the data from database and show it to customer and all other information from paypal you can handle in IPN, 2nd way, it's not best practice, use same url as IPN and return_url and then first handle the payment information and if all good show it to customer if not tell customer something goes wrong

Comment: I can't use a custom id since I'm only inserting rows into the database when the IPN gets a respons. So I wouldn't be able to set a custom ID before the transaction have been made. The return_url gets alot of info in the URL. like http://returnurl.com/?tx=123st=Complete and so on.. I've tried to fetch it with $_GET['tx'] but that creates some kind of error that's not displayed in PHP

Comment: if this is return_url `returnurl.com/?tx=123st=Complete` then it's wrong after `.com/` remove `/` and here `tx=123st=Complete` there must be `&` between `tx=123&st=Complete` should be like `domain.com/returnpagename.php?tx=123&st=Complete`

Comment: sorry, there is no / and the end of the domain. I mistyped.